# biblatex: Remove commas after author first names in References

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I'm using `biblatex-apa`

```
\documentclass[man]{apa7}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\addbibresource{y_bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}
\parencite{1} \newline
\parencite{2}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

`y_bibliography.bib` looks like this

```
@article{hanson2014business,
  title={Business student moral influencers: Unseen opportunities for development?},
  author={Hanson, William R and Moore, Jeffrey R},
  journal={Academy of Management Learning \& Education},
  volume={13},
  number={4},
  pages={525--546},
  year={2014},
  publisher={Academy of Management Briarcliff Manor, NY}
}

@article{hoornweg2011cities,
  title={Cities and greenhouse gas emissions: moving forward},
  author={Hoornweg, Daniel and Sugar, Lorraine and Trejos G{\'o}mez, Claudia Lorena},
  journal={Environment and urbanization},
  volume={23},
  number={1},
  pages={207--227},
  year={2011},
  publisher={SAGE Publications Sage UK: London, England}
}
```

The references in my compiled pdf document appear like this.

> Hanson, W. R., and Moore, J. R. (2014). Business student moral influencers: Unseen opportunities for development? Academy of Management Learning & Education, 13(4), 525–546.
>
> Hoornweg, D., Sugar, L., and Trejos Gómez, C. L. (2011). Cities and greenhouse gas emissions: Moving forward. Environment and urbanization, 23(1), 207–227.

I would like to remove commas after the second last author initials (before the 'and') and after the journal name so that the references appear like this

> Hanson, W. R. and Moore, J. R. (2014). Business student moral influencers: Unseen opportunities for development? Academy of Management Learning & Education 13(4), 525–546.
>
> Hoornweg, D., Sugar, L. and Trejos Gómez, C. L. (2011). Cities and greenhouse gas emissions: Moving forward. Environment and urbanization 23(1), 207–227.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a current version of `biblatex-apa`, the comma before the "and" is either by the Oxford comma (`\finalnamdelim`) or produced by the internal macro `\apablx@ifrevnameappcomma`. If you want to get rid of the comma, you need to disable both of these features.

The comma after the journal name can easily be converted to a space by messing with the `journal+issuetitle` macro and turning `\setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}` into `\setunit*{\addspace}`.

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\apablx@ifrevnameappcomma}[2]{#2}
\makeatother

\DefineBibliographyExtras{american}{%
  \let\finalandcomma=\empty
}

\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}%
  \printfield{eid}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{issuename}%
  \newunit}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{hanson2014business,
  title   = {Business Student Moral Influencers: Unseen Opportunities for Development?},
  author  = {Hanson, William R. and Moore, Jeffrey R.},
  journal = {Academy of Management Learning \& Education},
  volume  = {13},
  number  = {4},
  pages   = {525--546},
  year    = {2014},
}
@article{hoornweg2011cities,
  title   = {Cities and Greenhouse Gas Emissions: Moving Forward},
  author  = {Hoornweg, Daniel and Sugar, Lorraine and Trejos Gómez, Claudia Lorena},
  journal = {Environment and urbanization},
  volume  = {23},
  number  = {1},
  pages   = {207--227},
  year    = {2011},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{hanson2014business,hoornweg2011cities}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Hanson, W. R. & Moore, J. R. (2014). Business student moral influencers: Unseen opportunities for development? Academy of Management Learning & Education 13(4), 525–546. Hoornweg, D., Sugar, L. & Trejos Gómez, C. L. (2011). Cities and greenhouse gas emissions: Moving forward. Environment and urbanization 23(1), 207–227.]

Comment: Thanks a lot. this worked perfectly!

Comment: @Arpit If the answer solved your problem, please consider accepting it by clicking on the checkmark on the top left of the answer to show that the problem is resolved. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers.

Comment: done. Thanks again!